# SubString replacement in batch files batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

Hi i am trying to replace the contents of a text file using batchscript.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set line=0
set position=0
set replacetoken=POSITION
set newfile = new.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (resproprty.txt)  do  (
@echo off
set /a line+=1
if not !line!==1 (
set /a position+=1
)
set newcount=0
set newcount=!position!
set content=%%x
echo !content!
set content=!content:%replacetoken%=POSITION@!position!!
echo !newcount!
echo !position!
@echo on
echo !content! >> NEW.TXT
)
set test=Hello!
echo %test%
endlocal
```

here i am trying to replace my token `POSITION` with `POSITION@1`  i.e `POSITION@number` which is being incremented. however its not working !position! is not giving any output, i even tried `%position%` but that just gives output as 0. please help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
if exist output.txt del output.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a $count=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "resproprty.txt"') do (
set line=%%a
call set line=!line:POSITION=POSITION@%%$count%%!
echo !line!>>output.txt
set /a $count+=1
)

Echo ok
```

That will create the file `output.txt` with the change done

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "." q22988413.txt') DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 SET "line=!line:position=position@%%a!"
 ECHO(!line!
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22988413.txt` containing

```
Hello position one
Hello position two
Hello position three
Hello position four
Hello position five
```

which produced this output in `newfile.txt`

```
Hello position@1 one
Hello position@2 two
Hello position@3 three
Hello position@4 four
Hello position@5 five
```